# Focal length : 7.8 mm-46.8 mm (Equivalent to 35 mm-210 mm on a 35 mm camera)

Tags: bridge-camera

Bridge Camera : [Fujifilm S7000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujifilm_FinePix_S7000)

Could anyone help me to understand the below,

> Focal length : 7.8 mm-46.8 mm (Equivalent to 35 mm-210 mm on a 35 mm
>   camera)

I'm referring to DSLR based articles to learn photography . And I'm trying to follow [this Photograpy Life article](https://photographylife.com/what-is-reciprocal-rule-in-photography) but found above spec info in my camera confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most advanced photographers are quite a bit older than you. They learned photography using a 35mm film camera. Now the 35mm film camera has be around for nearly 100 years, so these serious photographers are also highly familiar with lenses they used with this camera.

Time marches on and the majority of digital cameras are smaller than the venerable 35mm film camera. So when they purchase a compact digital, they like to compare its shorter lenses to the longer lens associated with the bigger camera of their youth. Thus the equivalency was born. Your camera is about 4 ½ times smaller than the old 35mm film camera. This is called a magnification or crop factor. Multiply your camera’s lenses by about 4.5 and that what focal length would do about the same job on a 35mm film camera. My advice is to ignore this data for now.

Comment: "Most advanced photographers are quite a bit older than you" — every year, this is less and less true. :)

Answer (score 1):

This means that the angle of view and perspective of the lens of the Fujifilm S7000h equals the angle of view and perspective of a lens between 35 and 210 mm focal distance in an analogue reflex camera.

Comment: Lenses/focal lengths don't have perspective, shooting positions have perspective. Please see: [Is there a difference between taking a far shot on a 50mm lens and a close shot on a 35mm lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76321/15871)

Comment: Please see also: [What is the difference between perspective distortion and barrel or pincushion distortion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85526/15871)

Comment: And: [Does wide angle equivalent in crop sensor skew image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48337/15871)